# MVC 4 making a view (only single div on the particular cshtml webpage not whole webpage) dynamically changed according to the change in Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

let, I have a view in (.cshtml file) and this view's has a model which corresponds to my database class or table. In the view, I have many more different div or section.Let, inside one of the div or section I have some code which fetches data from my database table.  Now suppose, I have added/changed some data in that database. I don't want to reload the webpage(view) to view the changes; however, I just want to see the changes dynamically in that particular div which fetches data from database without reloading the full webpage.  I would be grateful if you provide me some solutions or redirect me to some good tutorials regarding this topic.

Comment: use ajax or signalr

Comment: could you please provide tutorial link ??

Comment: have a look into [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/302f8f/asp-net-mvc-real-time-app-with-signalr/) it might be helpful

Comment: As I am new on this platform,  can you guys provide some video tutorial?

Comment: Look at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us-Q3do-N7M) for getting started with signalR with MVC